# Regex match ONLY new lines in quotes in a larger string

Tags: javascript, regex, csv

I have a large CSV file and I want to find a regex capable of removing all new lines within quotes.

```
a123,b123,c123,d123,
a123,b123,c123,d123,
a123,b123,"c
123",d123,
a123,b123,c123,d123,
"a
123",b123,c123,d123,
a123,b123,c123,"d
1
2
3",
a123,b123,c123,d123,
a123,b123,c123,d123,
a123,b123,c123,d123
```

In this example, I have multiple rows where there is a new line in the quotes and even one where there are multiple new lines. I need to remove all of these new lines provided that they are within quotes. Is this possible?

Expected result:

```
a123,b123,c123,d123,
a123,b123,c123,d123,
a123,b123,"c123",d123,
a123,b123,c123,d123,
"a123",b123,c123,d123,
a123,b123,c123,"d123",
a123,b123,c123,d123,
a123,b123,c123,d123,
a123,b123,c123,d123
```

Node.js code:

```
var request = require('request')

request.post({
    url: '...',
}, function (error, response, body) {
    var formatted = body.replace(/.../g, '<#>')
})
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: The same string without new lines in the quotes

Comment: I'm sorry I still not get, can you edit your question and provide more information please

Comment: Only using regex it is not possible, what language are you using? Could you post the code that you are trying to use?

Comment: I am using Node.js but surely the language shouldn't matter?

Comment: It does quite a lot sadly. In the general case not all regex functionnality are implemented by all regex "flavours" (not all define shorthand classes, not all implement lookarounds, not all implement variable-width lookbehinds), but there are also different behaviours in implemented features (not all accept unescaped `-` at the beginning or end of a character class, not all refuse weird ranges such as a-Z in character classes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to match the content between quotes, then iterate through these matches and replace each one by the version without line-breaks...

```
let str = `a123,b123,c123,d123,
a123,b123,c123,d123,
a123,b123,"c
123",d123,
a123,b123,c123,d123,
"a
123",b123,c123,d123,
a123,b123,c123,"d
1
2
3",
a123,b123,c123,d123,
a123,b123,c123,d123,
a123,b123,c123,d123`;

const matches = str.match(/"[^"]+"/g);

matches.forEach(m => str = str.replace(m, m.replace(/[\r\n]/g, "")));

console.log(str);
```

Output in chrome console:

```
a123,b123,c123,d123,
a123,b123,c123,d123,
a123,b123,"c123",d123,
a123,b123,c123,d123,
"a123",b123,c123,d123,
a123,b123,c123,"d123",
a123,b123,c123,d123,
a123,b123,c123,d123,
a123,b123,c123,d123
```

Your Node.js code would be like this:

```
var request = require('request')

request.post({
    url: '...',
}, function (error, response, body) {
    let formatted = body;
    const matches = body.match(/"[^"]+"/g);
    matches.forEach(m => formatted = formatted.replace(m, m.replace(/[\r\n]/g, "")));
    console.log(formatted);
})
```

Comment: And remember, it's always best to ask about your problem, not about the solution that you tried to use and didn't work... It's more likely to have an answer with a solution that works and you didn't thought about.